# Please create tags for "Scribus" and "Scribus 1.4.x" and "Scribus 1.5.x"

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation-process

Scribus is getting more helpful and powerful each year. We have Python scripting (and serial printing) and questions are coming and will be coming more.

There is a stable series of Scribus and a series with more features (also rather stable) and it would help with the questions and answers to have said tags.

The link is pointing to a writeup about the two different series:

https://www.scribus.net/downloads/

Comment: Are people actually asking questions about this? Can you include links to some of them to make the tagging easier? (If there are no questions about it, the tags cannot and should not be created.)

Comment: [44 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=scribus%20is%3aq), if anything, only [tag:scribus] would be enough. But I wonder if it is even on-topic, I assume only for the scripting, right?

Comment: From the "we" and your profile, it appears as though you've worked on Scribus. Please do read http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support.

Comment: For the record: I am a part-time user of Scribus (publishing is just one of many project responsibilities) and have never worked for or with the Scribus team or organisation (if it exists). I wish I would be competent to program at that level.

I am working on development of a minority language in Africa and we face many technical challenges because even in the Unicode-system our language is not properly covered; we have to grab crumbs from several code-pages.

Comment: So helping new users - or users stuck with certain special needs - is a small way of giving back to the Scribus community. I like this place here and I get an e-mail each time a new question about Scribus is asked here. I am just trying to help, not trying to sell or promote anything. (Scribus is not being sold anyway, it is opensource.)

With certain special needs (characters not combining properly) a python script might save a user from overlooking occurrences of the problem, or just saving time from correctin many problem-spots manually.

Comment: Your answers so far sound very reluctant. 44 questions are "nothing" for some of you. Consider that Scribus is getting better every year - we just heard about a milestone, where the next Scribus will be able to support many new languages (right to left, Asian, etc.). So I guess there will be more questions.

Sorry, I did not realize that creating a tag might be very costly (by way of strain on your database or servers or maybe creating a tag takes a lot of time for one of the administrators in Stackoverflow).

Answer (score 3):

> Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel **you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.**

Frankly, I see this request as "I have this thing, create a tag for it". There are only 44 questions on the site that mention Scribus and frankly, the ones that I glanced at doesn't seem to be programming questions.

Unless you show us examples where there are on topic questions that no other tag would be applicable, I don't agree with the creation of any of these tags.

Comment: It looks like someone removed this tag from all the questions? IMHO at least for *some* of them the tag was appropriate IMHO. For example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25352813/660921), and probably most others with Python code that has `import scribus`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker afaik, none of the tags existed.

Comment: Oh, I thought the link in the comments was a tag search and that I was seeing a cached version of that search, but it turns out it was just a plain text search. Do'h! At any rate, the tag *would* still be on-topic for a very small number of on-topic questions.